# bowling game score calculator

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I'm new to the Developers world and I have project that I've been working on. It's to calculate the Bowling Game Score (similar to the Hdcp Score done by this tool: https://bowlinggenius.com/ )

I'm looking for a feedback to my code, from:
- Readability;
- the OOP SOLID principles and best-practice point of views (Encapsulation, Abstraction etc.)

Any suggestions on how to better refactor it?

Here is my code:

Game.cs

```
       using System;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Common;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Handlers;

namespace TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Modules
{
    public class Game
    {
        Frame[] ArrayOfFrames = new Frame[_maxFrameNumber];
        private int _currentFrameIndex = 0;

        private const int _maxFrameNumber = ConstTenPinsGameData.MaxFramesNumber;
        private readonly int _startingPinsNumber = ConstTenPinsGameData.StartingPinsNumber;
        private readonly int _finalFrameIndex = _maxFrameNumber - 1;
        private readonly GameHandler _gameHandler = new GameHandler();

        private bool _currentFrameIsNotSetYet => ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex] == null;
        private bool _isFinalFrame => _currentFrameIndex == _finalFrameIndex;
        private bool _frameBeforeLastIsAvailable => (_currentFrameIndex > 1) ? true : false;
        private bool _previousFrameIsAvailable => (_currentFrameIndex > 0) ? true : false;
        private bool _isCurrentFrameFinalWithBonus =>
            (ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex].FrameStatus == FrameStatus.TenthFrameWithBonus) ? true : false;



        public int Bowl(int kickedPins)
        {
            int gameScore = 0;
            ValidateKickedPinsInput(kickedPins);
            ValidateIfNewThrowAllowedForFinalFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex]);

            if (_currentFrameIsNotSetYet)
            {
                ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex] = new Frame();
                OrchestrateFramesWithFirstThrowScore(kickedPins);
            }
            else
            {
                OrchestrateFramesWithSecondThrowScore(kickedPins);
            }

            gameScore = ScoreCalculator.CalculateCurrentHdcpScoreFor(ArrayOfFrames, _currentFrameIndex);

            SetFrameIndexForNoneFinalFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex], kickedPins);

            return gameScore;
        }





        private void OrchestrateFramesWithFirstThrowScore(int kickedPins)
        {
            int previousFrameIndex = _currentFrameIndex - 1;
            int beforeLastFrameIndex = _currentFrameIndex - 2;

            if (_isFinalFrame)
                _gameHandler.SetFinalFrameFlagIfApplicable(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex]);

            _gameHandler.SetFirstScoreForNewFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex], kickedPins);

            if (_frameBeforeLastIsAvailable)
                _gameHandler.SetDifferentPropertiesForFrame(ArrayOfFrames[beforeLastFrameIndex], kickedPins);
            if (_previousFrameIsAvailable)
                _gameHandler.SetDifferentPropertiesForFrame(ArrayOfFrames[previousFrameIndex], kickedPins);

            _gameHandler.SetStatusForCurrentFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex]);
            _gameHandler.SetFrameClosedFlagIfStrike(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex]);
        }

        private void OrchestrateFramesWithSecondThrowScore(int kickedPins)
        {
            int previousFrameIndex = _currentFrameIndex - 1;

            if (_previousFrameIsAvailable)
                _gameHandler.SetDifferentPropertiesForFrame(ArrayOfFrames[previousFrameIndex], kickedPins);

            if (_isCurrentFrameFinalWithBonus)
                _gameHandler.SetDifferentPropertiesForFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex], kickedPins);
            else
                _gameHandler.SetPropertiesForCurrentFrame(ArrayOfFrames[_currentFrameIndex], kickedPins);
        }

        private void ValidateKickedPinsInput(int kickedPins)
        {
            if (kickedPins < 0 || kickedPins > _startingPinsNumber)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Sorry, your kickedPins '{kickedPins}' is out of allowed range 0-{_startingPinsNumber}. Pls check.");
        }

        private void ValidateIfNewThrowAllowedForFinalFrame(Frame currentFrame)
        {
            if (currentFrame != null && currentFrame.IsFinalFrame && currentFrame.IsFrameReadyForScore)
                throw new ArgumentException("Sorry, you have played All available bowl-throws for this game. Pls start a new game.");
        }

        private void SetFrameIndexForNoneFinalFrame(Frame currentFrame, int kickedPins)
        {
            if (!currentFrame.IsFinalFrame)
                SetFrameIndexBasedOnKickedPins(currentFrame, kickedPins);
        }

        private void SetFrameIndexBasedOnKickedPins(Frame currentFrame, int kickedPins)
        {
            if (kickedPins == _startingPinsNumber)
                _currentFrameIndex++;
            else if (currentFrame.IsFrameClose)
                _currentFrameIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

GameHandler.cs

```
    using System;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Common;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Modules;

namespace TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Handlers
{
    public class GameHandler
    {
        private readonly int _initialValueForBowlThrow = ConstTenPinsGameData.InitialValueForTheBowlThrow;
        private readonly int _startingPinsNumber = ConstTenPinsGameData.StartingPinsNumber;
        private readonly FrameHandler _frameHandler = new FrameHandler();

        private const int _thirdBowlForFrameWithoutBonus = 0;



        public void SetFirstScoreForNewFrame(Frame currentFrame, int kickedPins)
        {
            _frameHandler.SetFirstBowlForFrame(currentFrame, kickedPins);
        }

        public void SetFinalFrameFlagIfApplicable(Frame currentFrame)
        {
            _frameHandler.SetIsFinalFrameFlagToTrue(currentFrame);
        }

        public void SetPropertiesForCurrentFrame(Frame currentFrame, int kickedPins)
        {
            ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(currentFrame);
            ValidateSecondBowlValueForFrame(currentFrame, kickedPins);
            _frameHandler.SetSecondBowlForFrame(currentFrame, kickedPins);
            SetStatusForCurrentFrame(currentFrame);
            CompleteRegularFrame(currentFrame);
            _frameHandler.SetIsFrameClosedFlagToTrue(currentFrame);
        }

        public void SetStatusForCurrentFrame(Frame currentFrame)
        {
            ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(currentFrame);
            if (currentFrame.FirstBowlScore == _startingPinsNumber)
                _frameHandler.SetStatusForFrame(currentFrame, FrameStatus.Strike);
            else if (currentFrame.FirstBowlScore + currentFrame.SecondBowlScore == _startingPinsNumber)
                _frameHandler.SetStatusForFrame(currentFrame, FrameStatus.Spare);
            if (currentFrame.IsFinalFrame && (currentFrame.FrameStatus == FrameStatus.Strike ||
                                              currentFrame.FrameStatus == FrameStatus.Spare))
                _frameHandler.SetStatusForFrame(currentFrame, FrameStatus.TenthFrameWithBonus);
        }

        private void CompleteRegularFrame(Frame currentFrame)
        {
            ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(currentFrame);
            if (currentFrame.FirstBowlScore + currentFrame.SecondBowlScore != _startingPinsNumber)
                CompleteSettingPropertiesForFrame(currentFrame, _thirdBowlForFrameWithoutBonus);
        }


        public void SetFrameClosedFlagIfStrike(Frame currentFrame)
        {
            ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(currentFrame);
            if (currentFrame.FirstBowlScore == _startingPinsNumber)
                _frameHandler.SetIsFrameClosedFlagToTrue(currentFrame);
        }

        public void SetDifferentPropertiesForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(frame);
            if (frame.SecondBowlScore == _initialValueForBowlThrow)
                _frameHandler.SetSecondBowlForFrame(frame, kickedPins);
            else if (frame.ThirdBowlBonusScore == _initialValueForBowlThrow)
                CompleteSettingPropertiesForFrame(frame, kickedPins);
        }

        private void CompleteSettingPropertiesForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            _frameHandler.SetThirdBowlForFrame(frame, kickedPins);
            _frameHandler.SetIsReadyToScoreForFrameToTrue(frame);
        }

        private void ValidateSecondBowlValueForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            if (frame.FirstBowlScore + kickedPins > _startingPinsNumber)
                throw new ArgumentException($"The 2nd throw pins of {kickedPins} is higher than allowed for this frame. Pls check.");
        }

        private void ValidateFrameInputIsNotNull(Frame frame)
        {
            if (frame == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"The Frame provided {frame} is Null. Pls check.");
        }
    }
}
```

Frame.cs

```
    using System;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Common;

namespace TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Modules
{
    public enum FrameStatus
    {
        Regular,
        Strike,
        Spare,
        TenthFrameWithBonus
    }

    public class Frame
    {
        private readonly int _startingPinsNumber = ConstTenPinsGameData.StartingPinsNumber;

        public FrameStatus FrameStatus { get; private set; }

        public int FirstBowlScore { get; private set; } = -1;
        public int SecondBowlScore { get; private set; } = -1;
        public int ThirdBowlBonusScore { get; private set; } = -1;

        public bool IsFrameClose { get; private set; } = false;
        public bool IsFrameReadyForScore { get; private set; } = false;
        public bool IsFinalFrame { get; private set; } = false;



        public void SetFirstBowlScore(int kickedPinsCount)
        {
            if (kickedPinsCount >= 0 && kickedPinsCount <= _startingPinsNumber)
                FirstBowlScore = kickedPinsCount;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException($"The kicked pins count for 1st throw is '{kickedPinsCount}', but has to be between 0 and {_startingPinsNumber}.");
        }

        public void SetSecondBowlScore(int kickedPinsCount)
        {
            if (kickedPinsCount >= 0 && kickedPinsCount <= _startingPinsNumber)
                SecondBowlScore = kickedPinsCount;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException($"The kicked pins count for 2nd throw is '{kickedPinsCount}', but has to be between 0 and {_startingPinsNumber}.");
        }

        public void SetThirdBowlBonusScore(int kickedPinsCount)
        {
            if (kickedPinsCount >= 0 && kickedPinsCount <= _startingPinsNumber)
                ThirdBowlBonusScore = kickedPinsCount;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException($"The kicked pins count for 3rd (Bonus) throw is '{kickedPinsCount}', but has to be between 0 and {_startingPinsNumber}.");
        }

        public void SetIsFrameClosed(bool isSet)
        {
            IsFrameClose = isSet;
        }

        public void SetIsFrameReadyForScore(bool isSet)
        {
            IsFrameReadyForScore = isSet;
        }

        public void SetIsFinalFrame(bool isSet)
        {
            IsFinalFrame = isSet;
        }

        public void SetFrameStatus(FrameStatus frameStatus)
        {
            if (frameStatus == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The FrameStatus provided, is Null. Pls check.");
            FrameStatus = frameStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

FrameHandler.cs

```
    using System;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Common;
using TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Modules;

namespace TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Handlers
{
    public class FrameHandler
    {
        private readonly int _initialValueForBowlThrow = ConstTenPinsGameData.InitialValueForTheBowlThrow;


        public void SetFirstBowlForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            frame.SetFirstBowlScore(kickedPins);
        }

        public void SetSecondBowlForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            if (frame.SecondBowlScore == _initialValueForBowlThrow)
            {
                frame.SetSecondBowlScore(kickedPins);
            }
        }

        public void SetThirdBowlForFrame(Frame frame, int kickedPins)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            if (frame.ThirdBowlBonusScore == _initialValueForBowlThrow)
            {
                frame.SetThirdBowlBonusScore(kickedPins);
            }
        }

        public void SetIsReadyToScoreForFrameToTrue(Frame frame)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            if (frame.ThirdBowlBonusScore != _initialValueForBowlThrow)
            {
                frame.SetIsFrameReadyForScore(true);
            }
        }

        public void SetIsFrameClosedFlagToTrue(Frame frame)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            frame.SetIsFrameClosed(true);
        }

        public void SetStatusForFrame(Frame frame, FrameStatus frameStatus)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            frame.SetFrameStatus(frameStatus);
        }

        public void SetIsFinalFrameFlagToTrue(Frame frame)
        {
            ValidateForNull(frame);
            frame.SetIsFinalFrame(true);
        }



        private void ValidateForNull(Frame frame)
        {
            if (frame == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The Frame is Null. Pls check.");
        }
    }
}
```

ScoreCalculator.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BowlingGameHdcp
{
    public class ScoreCalculator
    {
        public static int CalculateCurrentHdcpScore(Frame[] arrayOfFrames, int currentFrameIndex)
        {
            var gameScore = 0;
            for (int countIndex = 0; countIndex <= currentFrameIndex; countIndex++)
            {
                if (arrayOfFrames[countIndex].IsFrameRedyForScore)
                    gameScore += arrayOfFrames[countIndex].FirstBowlScore +
                                 arrayOfFrames[countIndex].SecondBowlScore +
                                 arrayOfFrames[countIndex].ThirdBowlBonusScore;

            }

            return gameScore;
        }
    }
}
```

ConstTenPinsGameData.cs

```
namespace TenPinsBowlingGameHdcp.Common
{
    public static class ConstTenPinsGameData
    {
        public const int MaxFramesNumber = 10;
        public const int StartingPinsNumber = 10;
        public const int InitialValueForTheBowlThrow = -1;
    }
}
```

Program.cs (NOTE: This part is not of my concern, or at least not the biggest one :) )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BowlingGameHdcp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputListFrom = gameInput.Split(',');
            List<int> intInputList = new List<int>();

            var gameInputArray = new[]
            {
                "1",
                "1,1",
                "1, 1, 5",
                "10, 10",
                "10,10,10",
                "10,10,10,0",
                "10, 7, 3, 9, 0, 10, 0, 8, 8, 2, 0, 6, 10, 10, 10, 8, 1",
                "9, 0, 9,0, 9,0,9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 9,0 , 9,0, 9,0, 9,0",
                "5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,2",
                "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,2,0",
            };
            foreach (var singleGameInput in gameInputArray)
            {
                Game game= new Game();
                var inputListFrom = singleGameInput.Split(',');
                List<int> intInputList = new List<int>();



                foreach (var input in inputListFrom)
                {
                    input.Trim();
                    int charIntoIntInput = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                    intInputList.Add(charIntoIntInput);
                }

                int score = 0;
                foreach (var i in intInputList)
                {
                    score = game.Bowl(i);
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Current game input: `{singleGameInput}`");
                Console.WriteLine($" \t\t\t\t\t\t\t Current Total Score: {score}");
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to Quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `gameInputArray` an array of strings which you then need to split and convert to `int`s? Why not use a `List<List<int>>`?

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB. I'll check on it (the Program.cs, is not of a big concern to me, as it was merely just a check of the work, and not the request). Any concerns on the other classes? Should I split them more, or i.e. move GameHamdler part into FrameHandler class, and move most of the private methods from Game.cs into GameHandler.cs?